# Wordpress POST on the same page with Query String doesn't work

Tags: php, wordpress

On a WordPress custom template page (job-vacancies) I' am trying to post the form to the same page. As you see in the below code. The form action has the query string attached to it. For some reason when I attach the query string the form doesn't seem to work. It shows me same page without template. I have tried dumping form values on the page but its blank.

> Please note that the PHP codes will be written on the same page.

I have also tried changing the action to

```
<?php echo site_url();?>/careers/job-vacancies/?application=122
```

> Where is application=122 coming from? application=122 is coming from
>
> another page on the site from a link

```
<form id="formVacancy" method="post" action="/careers/job-vacancies/?application=122">   
        <input type="hidden" value="" name="wipit"/>
        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $application_id; ?>" name="application"/>
        <table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><div id="msg">Please fill in all the fields.</div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td width="26%"><div align="right">Full Name : &nbsp; </div></td>
                <td width="74%"><div align="left"><input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="right">Email Address :  &nbsp;</div></td>
                <td><div align="left"><input name="email" type="text" id="email" size="30"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="right">Phone Numher : &nbsp; </div></td>
                <td><div align="left"><input name="phone" type="text" id="phone" size="30"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="right">Attach Cover Letter : &nbsp;</div></td>
                <td><div align="left"><input name="cover" type="file" id="cover"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="right">Attach CV : &nbsp;</div></td>
                <td><div align="left"><input name="resume" type="file" id="resume"></div></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><div align="right"></div></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="button" id="button" value="Submit"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: why not pass the `application=122` in hidden input type?

Comment: I have edited the question, application=122 is coming from another page of the site another url that is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
<input name="name" type="text" id="name" size="30">
```

to:

```
<input name="fullname" type="text" id="fullname" size="30">
```

From experience WP has an issue posting a **name** as one of the fields.

Comment: And you are 1 million % correct. Was searching solution for this issue but no luck I think your experience thought me a lesson. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Worpress with short premalinks on is not passing get variables in url: as it is in wp codex "only retrieves public query variables that are recognized by WP_Query. This means that if you create your own custom URLs with their own query variables, get_query_var() will not retrieve them"
Instead registering variables I'm using function for it:

```
   function get_url_var() {
      $strURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
      $inst = explode("/", $strURL);
    $instno = (substr_count($strURL, '/')-1);
      $arrVals = split("/",$strURL);
      $found = $inst[$instno];
      return ($found == 0) ? 1 : $found;
   }
```

and then use get_url_var('application')